# How to troubleshoot Task not running in Task Schedule?

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks, windows-server

Task schedule drives me crazy.

I create a console application by C#, it will write "Hello World" to a .txt file. Then I create a new Task Schedule to run it. on my PC everything is perfect, then I move it to a dev-server, also works fine.

Now when I create the same Task schedule on client's Server(Windows server 2016), things become wired:

1. task can run first time, and 3-4 times more.
2. sunddenly, task doesn't run anymore, Last Run Time just not change (refreshed the list).
3. Last result always 'The operation completed successfully (0x0)'.
4. No any exception in History tab.
5. Console is NOT keep running in Task Manager

So since last time(long time ago) it worked successfully, then it never ran anymore, no error, no exception, nothing, I've no idea why it strike.

below are all my Task settings, I wish anyone can guide me, I believe it just a tiny problem:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that your task does not stop, so when a new task is run, it detects a previously running task and as such aborts the launch.

Given that you have set: stop the task if it runs longer than 3 days, it will run for 3 days. Given that the task is set to repeat for the entire day, it will appear to run for 4 days.

There are a few ways you can go about it, but my recommendation is to set the task as follows:

Change the schedule from daily to: at computer startup
Repeat task as desired, and set repeat cycle to indefinitely
Do not set the task automatically stop after 3 days.

This should give the desired effect. Do note, if you or someone else stops the task, the task will not run again until next reboot, so you do not want to stop the task unless you have to.

Lastly, set: if a task is already running, kill the previous task and start a new instance. Be sure that the task is not running longer than your delay, or strange things will happen. It is a known fact, that with Task Scheduler, tasks can complete normally, but Task scheduler does not detect this, and keeps it running.